# Space bug in my component

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, chess, gridlayoutmanager

I've nearly managed to build a chess board component with RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager, where the coordinates cells are half size than the cells ones. But I don't know why, there is a vertical gap between the left coordinates zone, and the first cells column (the "a" column).

[image: RecyclerViewTest]

The reason for that is to manage cells as ImageView so that I can work with a library like Glide.

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.loloof64.recycler_view_test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.loloof64.recycler_view_test.MainActivity">

    <com.loloof64.recycler_view_test.BoardComponent
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

BoardComponent.java :

```
package com.loloof64.recycler_view_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class BoardComponent extends RecyclerView {

    public BoardComponent(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public BoardComponent(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet  attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public BoardComponent(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context){
        setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, BoardComponentAdapter.ITEMS_PER_ROW));
        setAdapter(new BoardComponentAdapter(context));
    }
}
```

BoardComponentAdapter.java :

```
package com.loloof64.recycler_view_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class BoardComponentAdapter extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<BoardComponentViewHolder> {

    public final static int ITEMS_PER_ROW = 10;
    public final static int TOTAL_ITEMS = ITEMS_PER_ROW * ITEMS_PER_ROW;
    private final static int CELL_SIZE_DP = 20;

    private int cellSizePx;

    public BoardComponentAdapter(Context context){
        cellSizePx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CELL_SIZE_DP,  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }


    @Override
    public BoardComponentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.board_component, parent, false);
        return new BoardComponentViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BoardComponentViewHolder holder, int  position) {
        int rowPosition = position / ITEMS_PER_ROW;
        int colPosition = position % ITEMS_PER_ROW;

        boolean isACellRow = rowPosition > 0 && rowPosition < (ITEMS_PER_ROW-1);
        boolean isACellCol = colPosition > 0 && colPosition < (ITEMS_PER_ROW-1);

        if (isACellCol && isACellRow){
            int color = (rowPosition+colPosition) % 2 == 0 ? Color.rgb(255,180, 35) : Color.rgb(128,41,21);
            holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(color);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(cellSizePx, cellSizePx);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        else {
            int cellWidth = isACellCol ? cellSizePx : cellSizePx/2;
            int cellHeight = isACellRow ? cellSizePx : cellSizePx/2;
              holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(191,96,123));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(cellWidth, cellHeight);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return TOTAL_ITEMS;
    }
}
```

BoardComponentViewHolder.java

```
package com.loloof64.recycler_view_test;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BoardComponentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder     {

    public ImageView imageView;

    public BoardComponentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cell_view);
    }
}
```

board_component.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cell_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you suggest a better one ? I did not know how to resume my bug.

Comment: Already given : see the last code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

> It was happening because for border your are taking half of the height
>   and width as these parameters got half, The half place is there
>   unfilled i.e. why you are seeing GAP.

**Solution :**

> You can **leave left margin equal to your cell width** and the gap
>   will be gone..!! But just for the first column as you are having problem in first column only..!!

Tried your code. Just made change in your `BoardComponentAdapter.java` and working fine for me. see the change below:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BoardComponentViewHolder holder, int  position) {
    int rowPosition = position / ITEMS_PER_ROW;
    int colPosition = position % ITEMS_PER_ROW;

    boolean isACellRow = rowPosition > 0 && rowPosition < (ITEMS_PER_ROW-1);
    boolean isACellCol = colPosition > 0 && colPosition < (ITEMS_PER_ROW-1);

    if (isACellCol && isACellRow){
        int color = (rowPosition+colPosition) % 2 == 0 ? Color.rgb(255,180, 35) : Color.rgb(128,41,21);
        holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(cellSizePx, cellSizePx);
        holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
    else
    {
        int cellWidth = isACellCol ? cellSizePx : cellSizePx / 2;
        int cellHeight = isACellRow ? cellSizePx : cellSizePx / 2;
        holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(191, 96, 123));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(cellWidth, cellHeight);

        //Just Added three lines here..!!

        if(colPosition==0) {
            layoutParams.setMargins(cellWidth,0,0,0);
        }
        holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark is as correct if it solved the problem..!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay : I just needed to start Android Studio and Emulator to see the result. Thank you very much : the result is perfect.

Comment: It's fine.. I hope that helped..!!